Show that $\pi^*$ induces a map $\Omega(M) \rightarrow \tilde \Omega$.
This question is from an old publicly available qualifying exam that I’m using to learn this field (Stanford geometry and topology). All work is my own.


Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth, connected manifolds and let $\pi: M \times N \rightarrow M$ be the standard projection. A tangent vector $V$ to $M \times N$ is called vertical if $\pi_* V = 0$. For any $p$-form on $M \times N$ we define the $(p-1)$-form $\iota_V \omega$ by $$ (\iota_V \omega)(x_1 , \dots , x_{p-1}) = \omega(V, x_1, \dots, x_{p-1})$$ Consider $$ \tilde \Omega =  \{ \omega \in \Omega^* (M \times N) \mid \iota_V \omega  = 0    \text{ and } \iota_V(d \omega) = 0 \text{ for all vertical vectors } V\}.$$ Show that $\pi^*$ induces a map $\Omega(M) \rightarrow \tilde \Omega$.

Answer: We'll use Einstein summation convention where appropriate. Note that $\pi$ is an idempotent map. That is, for some coordinate $y = \pi(x)$ we have that $\pi(y) = y$.
Now, have the dimension of $M$ be $m$, and have $i \in 1, \dots, m$. For some form $\alpha_i dy_i$, we have the pullback $$ \pi^* (\alpha_i  dy_i) = \alpha_i  d(\pi y_i) = \alpha_i d(y_i)$$ which gives us an inclusion into an $m$ form on $M \times N$.
We know that $\pi_* V = 0$, which implies that it's orthogonal to every vector contained in the tangent bundle $TM$. As a result, any forms in $T^*M$ return zero when acting on $V$. Since $\pi^*$ acts as if it were the identity map on each form $ \omega \in \Omega(M)$, it follows that $\omega(V, \cdots) = 0$, which implies that $\omega \in \tilde \Omega$.
For the second condition, note that
$$\iota_V (dw) = d \omega(\cdots) = d(0) = 0$$ which satisfies the requirements. Then we clearly have an inclusion map $\boxed{\Omega(M) \rightarrow \tilde \Omega}$.

(a) Can I use the already present nullity to prove the second condition effortlessly?
As a bonus, even if my proof is correct, then let me know if there's a better tool or method to help me.
